# Unity 3D IMGUI Control, Gui. Button select /active use keyboard

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, button

For Unity3D Or need to use old OnGui/Gui.Button.

for an old project, I therefore cannot use the new UI because it would require the conversion of the entire project.
My problem that I can't solve, I searched for information everywhere on the web but I couldn't find any clear and simple solution to my problem.
Or need to select Gui.Button using keyboard key:
A / S or UpArrow/Down Arrow to scroll/select all Single Gui Button.

Just like you would by hovering over it with your mouse.
I managed to find a simple solution to simulate Pressing Click  the mouse using the A key on the keyboard, is there an equally simple solution to do this?
I thank

void OnGUI () {

if (GUI.Button (new Rect (25, 25, 100, 30), Button")|| Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.A)){

|| Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.A)){//this active :click :Entering input key here will perfectly simulate pressing the key with a single frame by adding Up and not Down.

But for select single GUI, Button Using a keyboard key?

Use press key for simulate select  mouse single Gui. Button?

Example:
Press the A/DownArrow key = select:

1-Gui. Button ("Start game")

Press the A/DownArrow key = select:

2-Gui. Button (''Option'')

Press the A/DownArrow key = select:

3-Gui. Button ("Exit game")

---

Press the S/UpArrow key = select:

1-Gui. Button ("Exit Game")

Press the S/UpArrow key = select:

2-Gui. Button (''Option'')

Press the S/UpArrow key = select:

3-Gui. Button ("Start Game")

Comment: pls edit your post and correctly format the code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want is to select and go through controls similar like you would using the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key in a browser.

As you say this is quite simple using the UI systems which have this built-in.

Using only `OnGUI` this might be a bit complex. It *can* be done though using things like [`GUI.SetNextControlName`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.SetNextControlName.html), [`GUI.FocusControl`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.FocusControl.html), [`GUI.GetNameOfFocusedControl`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.GetNameOfFocusedControl.html) and [`Event.current`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Event-current.html).

Then for each button you need to

- Define a unique name/ID (for instance e.g. the label)
- Define the 4 neighbors to select next according to the arrow key press

Here is an example I roughly build to show the usages

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    // info about which next UI to select when pressing arrow keys
    private class FocusInfo
    {
        public string Right {get;}
        public string Left { get;}
        public string Up { get;}
        public string Down { get;}

        public FocusInfo(string right, string left, string up, string down)
        {
            Right = right;
            Left = left;
            Up = up;
            Down = down;
        }
    }

    // info about which next UI to select when pressing arrow keys for each button
    private readonly Dictionary<string, FocusInfo> focusInfos = new Dictionary<string, FocusInfo>();

    // currently focused control
    // used to keep focus on the last focused control even if clicked somewhere else
    private string currentFocused;

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        DrawAndRegisterButton(new Rect(10, 10, 100, 30), "Top Left",()=>
        {
            Debug.Log("Top Left");
        }, "Top Center", null, null, "Middle Left");
    

        DrawAndRegisterButton(new Rect(Screen.width - 110, 10, 100, 30), "Top Right",()=>
        {
            Debug.Log("Top Right");
        }, null, "Top Center", null, "Middle Right");

        DrawAndRegisterButton(new Rect(10, Screen.height - 40, 100, 30), "Bottom Left",()=>
        {
            Debug.Log("Bottom Left");
        }, "Bottom Center", null, "Middle Left", null);

        DrawAndRegisterButton(new Rect(Screen.width - 110, Screen.height - 40, 100, 30), "Bottom Right",()=>
        {
            Debug.Log("Bottom Right");
        }, null, "Bottom Center", "Middle Right", null);

        DrawAndRegisterButton(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 50, 10, 100, 30), "Top Center",()=>
        {
            Debug.Log("Top Center");
        }, "Top Right", "Top Left", null, "Bottom Center");

        DrawAndRegisterButton(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 50, Screen.height - 40, 100, 30), "Bottom Center", ()=>
        {
            Debug.Log("Bottom Center");
        }, "Bottom Right", "Bottom Left", "Top Center", null);

        DrawAndRegisterButton(new Rect(10, Screen.height / 2 - 15, 100, 30), "Middle Left", ()=>
        {
            Debug.Log("Middle Left");
        }, "Middle Right", null, "Top Left", "Bottom Left");

        DrawAndRegisterButton(new Rect(Screen.width - 110, Screen.height / 2 - 15, 100, 30), "Middle Right", ()=>
        {
            Debug.Log("Middle Right");
        }, null, "Middle Left", "Top Right", "Bottom Right");

        HandleKeybord();

        InitializeOnceWithFocus("Top Left");
            
        KeepFocusOnCurrent();
    }

    // Simplify drawing and registering of buttons
    // Assuming for now that label = unique ID
    // Includes assigning name to each control so they can be focused later
    private void DrawAndRegisterButton( Rect rect, string label, Action onClick, string right, string left, string up, string down)
    {
        GUI.SetNextControlName(label);
        if (GUI.Button(rect, label))
        {
            onClick?.Invoke();
        }

        if(!focusInfos.ContainsKey(label))
        {
            focusInfos.Add(label,new FocusInfo(right, left, up, down));
        }
    }

    // At the beginning of the game, focuses the first button
    private void InitializeOnceWithFocus(string focus)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(currentFocused)) return;

        GUI.FocusControl(focus);
        currentFocused = focus;
    }

    // Handles the arrow keys and focuses the next UI
    private void HandleKeybord()
    {
        var e = Event.current;
        if(e.type != EventType.KeyDown) return;

        switch(e.keyCode)
        {
            case KeyCode.UpArrow:
            case KeyCode.DownArrow:
            case KeyCode.RightArrow:
            case KeyCode.LeftArrow:    
                FocusNext(e.keyCode);
                break;
        }
    }

    // Focuses the next UI based on the arrow key pressed
    private void FocusNext(KeyCode keyCode)
    {
        var current = GUI.GetNameOfFocusedControl();

        if(!focusInfos.TryGetValue(current, out var info)) return;
        
        var next = keyCode switch {
        
            KeyCode.UpArrow => info.Up,
            KeyCode.DownArrow => info.Down,
            KeyCode.RightArrow => info.Right,
            KeyCode.LeftArrow => info.Left,
            _ => null
        };

        if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(next))
        {
            currentFocused = next;
            GUI.FocusControl(next);
        }
    }

    // Maintains the focus on currentFocused if e.g. clicked anywhere 
    private void KeepFocusOnCurrent()
    {
        if(!focusInfos.ContainsKey(GUI.GetNameOfFocusedControl()))
        {
            GUI.FocusControl(currentFocused);
        }
    }
}
```

A bit hard to see but basically starts of with the top-left selected per default - then I am using the 4 arrow keys to focus on different buttons and click using <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Return</kbd>

[image]

---

I just saw now that you edited your question and put more information in - in particular that you actually only require up/down which of course simplifies the use case a lot. You could then even use a simple List instead of a Dictionary and just go in order of the code.

I will stick to the original answer as it is more generic and covers other's use cases as well. (Even though, let's be honest, who will still use `OnGUI` anyway ;) )

Comment: error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Action' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Thanks For your great help, And the same script shown in your video?or tried to test it on Unity 2023 but it has Critical errors and doesn't work can't run you can check and fix the critical errors.
  Line 84 Action I don't know what it refers to if I try to exclude it it generates other critical errors.
Thank you. I hope for your help

Comment: maybe try and add `using System;` ... [`Action`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.action) basically just equals a parameterless `delegate void Action();` ... a signature prototype meaning you can pass any parameterless void method or lambda expression ... made this all with Unity 2021 LTS but I'm pretty sure it should work the same in 2023

Comment: Hi do you mean to trade like this with Action   ?......private void DrawAndRegisterButton( Rect rect, string label, System; onClick, string right, string left, string up, string down)

Comment: this portion script Anomaly line 137 and138 ?: _ => null
        }; Change  Action add System; but appeared 25 Critical Error 1-..................Example.cs(155,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected----------2-Example.cs(148,5): error CS0106: The modifier 'private' is not valid for this item------------3-Example.cs(125,5): error CS0106: The modifier 'private' is not valid for this item----------4-xample.cs(108,5): error CS0106: The modifier 'private' is not valid for this item-------

Comment: 5-Example.cs(99,5): error CS0106: The modifier 'private' is not valid for this item----6-Example.cs(96,5): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected--7-Example.cs(92,9): error CS8803: Top-level statements must precede namespace and type declarations--8-Example.cs(89,21): error CS1519: Invalid token '.' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration-9 -Example.cs(87,36): error CS1519: Invalid token ')' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration

Comment: ecc.....I don't know LTS -probably the script is not compatible with Unity standard ,

Comment: no, I meant add `using System;` at the top of the script and everything is fine .. added it to the code here  ... just tested on 2023.2.5 and everything is fine there as well ;) .... however, if you are on 2023 you should really really rather go and use the UI systems available there tbh.

Comment: Hi Thanks add  using System; --using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;  but 26 Critical Error

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, it has 26 critical errors

Comment: Not on my machine ^^ you're doing something wrong - I also just copy&paste the code from here into a new project and it does what you can see in the gif

Comment: Are the errors in Unity or only your code editor?

Comment: my procedure 1-create new script name Example ,copy paste script save and appera 26 error critical

Comment: [link](https://postimg.cc/hQPTsnDD) 8 Critical Error

Comment: well this just says you have now two scripts called `Example` in your project ...

Comment: Hi thanks Sorry I had added another new script and I hadn't deleted the second script now everything works fine you're great now everything works perfectly not so just how to thank you

Comment: I preferred to change in UI but I was unable to convert this line of code to make it compatible with the new UI interface

Comment: I managed to do this with a normal GuiButton that uses tex
I'll show you example scripts that work, the text is transferred to the text of the new UI

Comment: well for images you would rather an [`UI.Image`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.2/Documentation/Manual/script-Image.html) and for the clicks [`UI.Button`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.2/Documentation/Manual/script-Button.html) component .. but it's a bit hard right now to tell what you are doing, I'm losing a bit track ^^ This question was mainly focused on how to focus and switch focus of UI elements created with the oldschool `OnGUI` .. if you have a different approach and new questions feel free to do a new research and then open new questions while hitting blockers ;)

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me on my OnGui,Button request you were able to solve my problem,Thank you, Thank you, Thank you, I will try to ask another question to try to resolve this problem as well

Comment: PROBLEM SUCCESSFULLY SOLVED

Comment: Can a specific key be added when the button is pressed?  EventType.KeyDown :EventType.KeyDown=E or R - because I read that In event Down and Up cannot be changed directly   non possible add Type.KeyDown.R or Type.Key.R thanks

Comment: Ok Solved by itself to simulate hovering over a Gui.Button just add this single line of code above each of your OnGui.Button like this: ---- GUI.SetNextControlName("1");--this code simulate active Mouse Over and Click Mouse -works with both keyboard and pad buttons, unique short code to use keyboard and pad keys in your OnGui.Button, allows you to select all your OnGUI.Button buttons using keyboard and pad – 
Wonder76
9 mins ago

Comment: test video pad and keyboard :https://youtu.be/rPcEKAincUA

Comment: all with just one line of clean, simple code: GUI.SetNextControlName("1");